# Passing arguments in URL while using routing in PHP

Tags: php, routes

I implimented the routing in php, Everything is working fine except when I try to send data on url like this :

```
http://localhost/search/?sprefix=all
```

and sometime it looks like this :

```
http://localhost/search/?sprefix=Sippers%20&%20Mugs+sprefix_sub=children%20mugs
```

Here is my routing

```
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch ($request) {
    case '/search/':
        require __DIR__ . '/views/Product/Search/Search.php';
        break;
}
?>
```

and the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Can someone help me to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the full path, including the query string. You can use [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) on the URL and fetch the `path` param from the results to only get the path value.

Comment: ...and for future reference, don't add tags that doesn't have anything to do with your question (in this case, html and javascript, which I've now removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$_GET[]` or `parse_url()` to solve you problem

Comment: How would using `$_GET` solve their issue when they want to compare the uri without the query string? Also, when writing an answer, include a proper example instead of just mentioning a function name.